# Not able to merge to Map<String, Long>

Tags: collections, java-8

I am trying to merge several Map into a single map, for doing this I wrote this piece of code.

```
public static Map<String, Long> mergeMaps(List<Map<String, Long>> maps){
    Map<String, Long> mergedMap = new TreeMap<>();
    maps.forEach( map -> {
        //Map<String, Long> mx = new TreeMap<>(map);
        map.forEach((key, value) -> mergedMap.merge(key, value, Long::sum));
    });
    logger.info("Merge map successful");
    return mergedMap;
}
```

On doing this the code is throwing an error :

```
org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[?:1.8.0_201-1-ojdkbuild]
lambda$mergeMaps$1
```

I have this pojo

public class MappingDto {

```
public MappingDto(){

    map1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map3 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
}

private Map<String, Long> map1;
private Map<String, Long> map2;
private Map<String, Long> map3;

getters()/Setters()
toString()
}
```

I populate this pojo maps with the below codes.

```
MappingDto.setMap1(Arrays.asList(doc.getDescription().split("\\s+")).stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),LinkedHashMap::new,Collectors.counting())));
```

after generating this I have to merge this map with the some Stored in File, To read the Map I have the below method.

```
public static <T> T readJsonFile(String filePath, T t) throws JAXBException, IOException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    if(!Utils.checkIfFileExists(filePath)){
        Utils.createANewFile(filePath);
        return t;
    }
    return mapper.readValue(new File(filePath), new TypeReference<T>(){});
}
```

After getting this maps I pass it to the

```
mergeMaps(Arrays.asList(MappingDto.getMap1(),storedData));
```

and

```
List<Map<String, Long>> dataList = new LinkedList<>();
dataList.add(MappingDto.getMap1());
dataList.add(MappingDto.getMap2());
dataList.add(MappingDto.getMap3());
mergeMaps(dataList);
```

I went through this code several time, But not able to figure what exactly is causing this issue.

One is reading the Stored JSON map

```
public static <T> T readJsonFile(String filePath, Class<T> t) throws JAXBException, IOException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    if(!Utils.checkIfFileExists(filePath)){
        Utils.createANewFile(filePath);
        return t.newInstance();
    }
    return mapper.readValue(new File(filePath), new TypeReference<T>(){});
}
```

I tried this and several other variations but no results.

```
public static Map<String, Long> mergeMaps(List<Map<String, Long>> maps){
    Map<String, Long> mergedMap = new TreeMap<>();
    maps.forEach( map -> {
        //Map<String, Long> mx = new TreeMap<>(map);
        map.forEach((key, value) -> mergedMap.merge(key, Long.valueOf(value), Long::sum));
    });
    logger.info("Merge map successful");
    return mergedMap;
}
```

Can you please help me understand what is in Integer and why is being cast to Long

Thanks in advance.

Comment: weird where this is coming from... it works just fine

Comment: Can you show where you invoke the method and where it's built? I can assure you're putting an `Integer` reference inside as a value... This bug has been known already

Comment: probably your error have happened in `getStoredMap(fileName);`

Comment: `public Map<String, Long> callMerge(String fileName, Map<String, Long> data) {
 Map<String, Long> storedData = getStoredMap(fileName);
 return mergeMaps(Arrays.asList(data,storedData));
}`

Here I am reading a stored map in JSON format amd merging the one currently formed and there is an overloaded method

`public void callMerge(String fileName, List<Map<String, Long>> data) throws  IOException {
 Map<String, Long> storedData = getStoredMap(fileName);
 data.add(storedData);
 return mergeMaps(data);
}`

Comment: @Hadi If you look at storedData, Its of Type Map<String Long> That's of type Long no Integer references there. Why look for integer in this case.

Comment: @Lucie Please edit your post and show where the Map is created and filled.

Comment: @Lucie Because it's a well-known bug

Comment: I Figured out the issue.
On calling readJsonFile() with Map<String, Long> the method Still returns Map<String, Integer>.
I tried to fix this by using this code : 
`map.entrySet().parallelStream().collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(), entry -> Long.valueOf(entry.getValue())));
`

But now this method started throwing same issue. Please help me fixing this issue.